# If f is a continuous mapping from a connected metric space X to Y, prove that the graph is connected in the product metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

[image]

I might be missing something but shouldn't this proof be trivial since X is connected, then f(X) is also connected, and the cartesian product of two connected metric spaces is connected. Of course, the whole space X x Y may not be connected, but X x f(X) should be a connected sub metric space right?

Comment: The Cartesian product $X \times f(X) \neq G(f)$. Indeed, if $x, x'\in X$ and $f(x) \neq f(x')$, then $(x, f(x'))$ is in $X \times f(X)$, but not in $G(f)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is not correct becasue the graph is not a  product set in general. In fact it  is a product set only when $f$ is a constant function!.

$x \to (x,f(x))$ is a continuous map from $X$ into $X \times Y$. Continuous image of  a connected space is connected and the image here is exactly the graph of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

To me the slickest way to do this is to extend the map $f:X\to Y$ to a map $Id_X\times f: X\to X\times Y$.  Clearly the $G(f)$ is the image of this map $Id_X\times f$.  All we need to do is simply prove that the mapping is continuous.  For a product open set $U\times V \subseteq X\times Y$ we see that $(Id_X\times f)^{-1}(U\times V) = U\cap f^{-1}(V)$ which is open in $X$.  Now any open set is written as the union of these product open sets in the product topology on $X\times Y$ so we find

$$
(Id_X \times f)^{-1} \left (\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha \times V_\alpha \right ) \;\; =\;\; \bigcup_\alpha (Id_X\times f)^{-1} (U_\alpha\times V_\alpha) \;\; =\;\; \bigcup_\alpha (U_\alpha \cap f^{-1}(V_\alpha))
$$

where we use the fact that the inverse image of a union is the same as the union of the inverse images.  Since each $U_\alpha\cap f^{-1}(V_\alpha)$ is open and we are taking an arbitrary union of these, we find that the inverse image is open and thus $Id_X\times f$ is continuous.  Since $X$ is connected, then its image $G(f)$ will be connected in $X\times Y$.